# Github action with code inspection for dotnet

Tags: .net, github, github-actions, code-inspection

I got a little bit stuck on my github action for testing and inspecting code. Problem comes with inspection, I got that part with analysing and end up with xml file, but how can I report those issues back to workflow manager and report errors?

My github action yml file.

```yaml
  code_inspection:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup .NET 3
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: 3.1.301
      - name: Setup .NET 5
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: 5.0.100
      - name: Add dotnet tool
        run: dotnet tool restore
      - name: Analyse
        run: dotnet jb inspectcode Solution.sln -o=output.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/resharper-cli-inspectcode

There is an action inspect code with ReSharper Command Line Tool. Inspection result is annotate to PR File Change Tab.